# designing layout of magento 2 theme

Tags: magento, inheritance, layout, themes

I am new to Magento.

I am creating Magenta 2 site, I have managed to install Magento, and for it to use the luma theme.

I want to be able to edit the theme (through Inheritance), I understand it uses XML files to design the layout, how do I change these, should they be in the new theme folder, and change them there?

If so, where do I get the origonal Luma xml files, or does magento create these? - There are no themes within the app/ folder, is it here where I create the new theme (that inherits from Luma)?

Many thanks for any help, I am completely new to Magento.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom theme and make `theme.xml` and set a parent to LUMA.
Now `app/design/frontend/customthemename`

So anything that you want to customized used in customthemename folder

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create a child theme to edit XML file. To create a child theme, there are 3 steps to do:

Firstly, create a new theme directory in app/design/frontend.

Secondly, declare the new theme by:

- Creating theme.xml: this file identifies the name, parent and other
  basic info of the new theme.
- Creating Composer.json: this file is used to install the theme via Composer later.
- Creating registration.php: this file is required in any Magento 2 Extension
  and Themes.
- Creating static files directories: this folder is used to store CSS, JS, image files.
- Creating logo folder: this folder contains files that determine the location and size of your new theme logo.

Thirdly, apply and configure theme in admin: - Run Upgrade Command. - Apply the theme. - Deploy.

For more detailed tutorial, go to [Guide to create Magento 2 theme](https://bssthemes.com/blog/create-magento-2-theme/).

2. The original XML files of any module and themes are located in vendor/magento//view/frontend/layout, with the module_name is the module related to the XML file you want to edit.

For example, with homepage CMS, the XML file is located in `vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout`